# Send a XML request using jQuery

Tags: xml, jquery, asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

I want to communicate with the UPS API via jQuery and AJAX. The XML seems to be well formed, as it works fine in a similar ASP script. But I figured I would skip the ASP script and communicate directly with UPS via jQuery. However, when I send the request, the response comes up as:

METHOD: OPTIONS
Status: Load Cancelled

I assume I missed some kind of option in the ajax request that tells it to send the xml to the UPS server.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({ type: "POST",
                            url: "https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/XAV",
                            data: "<?xml version=1.0?>" + 
                                "   <AccessRequest xml:lang='en-US'>" +
                                "       <AccessLicenseNumber>LICENSENUMBER</AccessLicenseNumber>" +
                                "       <UserId>USER</UserId>" +
                                "       <Password>PASS</Password>" +
                                "   </AccessRequest>" +
                                "   <?xml version=1.0?>" +
                                "   <AddressValidationRequest xml:lang='en-US'>" +
                                "       <Request>" +
                                "           <TransactionReference>" +
                                "               <CustomerContext>AddressValidationRequest</CustomerContext>" +
                                "               <XpciVersion>1.0</XpciVersion>" +
                                "           </TransactionReference>" +
                                "           <RequestAction>XAV</RequestAction>" +
                                "           <RequestOption>3</RequestOption>" +
                                "       </Request>" +
                                "       <AddressKeyFormat>" +
                                "           <AddressLine>1234 N. Main Street</AddressLine>" +
                                "           <PoliticalDivision2>Los Angeles</PoliticalDivision2>" +
                                "           <PoliticalDivision1>CA</PoliticalDivision1>" +
                                "           <PostcodePrimaryLow>90210</PostcodePrimaryLow>" +
                                "           <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>" +
                                "       </AddressKeyFormat>" +
                                "   </AddressValidationRequest>", 
                            contentType: "text/xml",
                            dataType: "xml",
                            cache: false,
                            error: function() { alert("No data found."); },
                            success: function(xml) {
                                alert("it works");
                                alert($(xml).find("project")[0].attr("id"));
                            }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Your browser is treating it as a CORS request. Try adding _crossDomain: true,_

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are making a Cross Domain call.
You would need to use jsonp for Cross Domain calls. Refer [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> **crossDomain** (default: false for same-domain requests, true for
>   cross-domain requests) Type: Boolean If you wish to force a
>   crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same domain, set the value
>   of crossDomain to true. This allows, for example, server-side
>   redirection to another domain. (version added: 1.5)